# difference between <% and <%= ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been working through some ruby on rails tutorials, and I see that the <% %> and <%= %> symbols are used for inline ruby, but what is the difference between those two pairs of symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are generally used in embedded ruby (erb) files.

`<% %>` is to execute the Ruby code within brackets, `<%= %>` is to print output in the file.